# Race Condition inside Parallel.Foreach with List

Tags: vb.net, list, task-parallel-library, race-condition, parallel.foreach

I need help on how to resolve this race condition. Below is the code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                        ' Do something...
                        dim newPeople as new List(Of Person)
                        dim myNames as ConcurrentBag(Of String) = GetNames()

                        Parallel.ForEach(myNames, Sub(name)
                                            Dim person as new Person
                                            person.Name = name
                                            person.Gender = "MALE"

                                            newPeople.Add(person)
                                            GridView.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                    GridView.DataSource = newPeople
                                                                End Sub)

                                            ' Do something...

                                            dim index as Integer = newPeople.FindIndex(Function(p) p.Name = name) ' Race condition error
                                            newPeople(index).Gender = "FEMALE"

                                            GridView.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                    GridView.DataSource = newPeople
                                                                End Sub)

                                        End Sub)

                     End Sub, param ,TaskCreationOptions.None)
```

What this code basically does is this:

- Set the name and gender of the person in the object
- Add this person object in the person list
- Display in grid view (to display the before and after)
- After do something, change the gender of person
- Display in gridview after the person element has been updated.

**End Result:** The gridview will automatically change the status during the execution of the tasks.

I'm running out of ideas on how to get past this. Could you suggest anything to resolve this?

Comment: What happens during `do something`? Is it relevant?

Comment: The `do something` processes the data based on the table name. Once it is done, it updates (or should update) the Gender of the object inside the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. It is by changing `List(Of T)` to `ConcurrentBag(Of T)` resolved the issue. According to the [this link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ConcurrentBag.aspx)

> The `ConcurrentBag<T>` collection, in the System.Collections.Concurrent
>   namespace, provides a multiset that is thread-safe. The collection
>   allows you to **add and remove items freely from multiple threads**
>   **without having to worry about thread synchronisation.** The fact that
>   the bag has no ordering allows it to be particularly efficient when
>   you have multiple threads or parallel tasks where each both adds and
>   removes items.